# How to create and use environment variable .env yii2

Tags: yii2

I want to create a file .env:

```
 FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID=*****
 FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET=*****
```

and use variable for config

```
'facebook' => [
                'class' => 'yii\authclient\clients\Facebook',
                'clientId' => env('FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID'),
                'clientSecret' => env('FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET'),
            ],
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 9):

I have found the solution.

I use package  [vlucas/phpdotenv](https://packagist.org/packages/vlucas/phpdotenv).

Thank for all

Comment: this module works perfect to me not sure why someone give you a negative

Comment: I tried to use it, but no idea where to load it to be used everywhere. How did you do it ?

Answer (score 3):

There's a package for Yii2 you can use for dotenv

https://github.com/yiithings/yii2-dotenv

### Install:

```
composer require --prefer-dist yiithings/yii2-dotenv "*"
```

### Usage:

Create a `.env` in project root directory

```
DB_HOST="localhost"
DB_NAME="yii2basic"
DB_USER="root"
DB_PASS="YourPassword"
```

config/db.php

```
return [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn' => 'mysql:host='. env('DB_HOST') .';dbname='. env('DB_NAME'),
    'username' => env('DB_USER'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASS'),
    'charset' => 'utf8',
];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can archive this by Utilizing the enviroment constants. If you are using Yii2 advanced when you initialize your application as dev or production yii sets a constant YII_ENV as either dev or production in your index.php entry script.

If you are using yii basic you can set it as per your enviroment. For example we want to define config for dev.

We will proceed and edit our /web/index.php to

```
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');
```

Then in our config file we would have the following

```
'facebook' => [
    'class' => 'dektrium\user\clients\Facebook',
    'clientId' => (YII_ENV_DEV ? 'Your key when in developent' : 'Your Key if not in developement'),
    'clientSecret' => (YII_ENV_DEV ? 'Your key when in developent' : 'Your Key if not in developement'),
],
```

Refere to this for more details on **Enviroment Constants** http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-configurations.html#environment-constants

Comment: Thank you, I have found the solution

Answer (score 0):

You could use the dotenv package offered by Symfony. https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dotenv.html

using it in a PHP file.

```
use Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv;

$dotenv = new Dotenv();
$dotenv->load(__DIR__.'/.env');

// You can also load several files
$dotenv->load(__DIR__.'/.env', __DIR__.'/.env.dev');
```

.env file

```
DB_USER=root
DB_PASS=pass
```

accessing the variables from the .env file

```
$dbUser = $_ENV['DB_USER'];
// you can also use ``$_SERVER``
```